# how to get column count in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

i have a query below

```
select emp_id,
  sum(case when leave_type = 'Planned' then 1 else 0 end) Planned,
  sum(case when leave_type = 'Not Informed' then 1 else 0 end) NotInformed,
  sum(case when leave_type = 'Informed' then 1 else 0 end) Informed
from table where activity_type='Leave'
group by emp_id
```

it gives below result

[image]

how to get count for above columns for 567 it will display 3
and for 619 it will display 4 in separate column please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a COUNT() column:

```
select emp_id,
  sum(case when leave_type = 'Planned' then 1 else 0 end) Planned,
  sum(case when leave_type = 'Not Informed' then 1 else 0 end) NotInformed,
  sum(case when leave_type = 'Informed' then 1 else 0 end) Informed,
  count(*) as Total
from t
where activity_type='Leave'
group by emp_id;
```

> ```
> emp_id | planned | notinformed | informed | total
> -----: | ------: | ----------: | -------: | ----:
>    619 |       2 |           1 |        1 |     4
>    567 |       0 |           3 |        0 |     3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=2f9a5f74f3d520a8e521592cb527f401)*